# Swift game volume/speaker icon

Tags: swift

I am making a game that has sound fx, and I want a button you press to turn the sounds on and off. I want it to look like the ios icon when you adjust your volume, and have a line through it when you press it to turn it off. How do I achieve this? Do I use a picture? Where would I find that? I see it every where on games, so there has to be a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `UIButton`, set its image to be a speaker icon and change it when it is pressed.

As far as I am aware there is no way to access the built in iOS sound icon so you could either create your own or find suitable icons elsewhere. [For example, these.](http://adamwhitcroft.com/batch/) This pack has speaker icons that show different volume levels and also one with a cross next to it. Not **exactly** what you are looking for but it may help.